# Term Symbols of Carbon Atom

Tags: atomic-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle, orbitals, term-symbols

For a neutral Carbon Atom, the electron (ground) configuration is $1s^2$$2s^2$$2p^2$.  I am told that the term symbols $^{3}S_{1}$ and $^{3}D_{1,2,3}$ are forbidden by Pauli Exclusion Principle.

May I ask why is this the case?

Comment: NIST is off-line because of US politics! (I wanted to check the assertion on https://www.nist.gov/ )

Comment: @Pieter RIP it's actually a sad thing that politics take part in the scientific community... my assertions are correct though; I've checked several sources that those term symbols stated are forbidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Existence of the $^1D$ term and the non-existence of the $^3D$ term?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304605/)